# setting background color to white makes line in progress bar invisible

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My form looks like this:
[image]

After setting container to:

```
<div class="container" style="background:white;">
```

[image]

How i can make it on white and this progress bar line visible?

```
CSS: 

    https://pastebin.com/0hnUjRm7

HTML: 

    https://pastebin.com/Wc2zWkiJ
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: Please edit your question and use the snippet button to include the code - please read [something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Ok i will add but i explained whats wrong. After adding style="background: white" progress bar line disappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add css file in #progressbar li property to z-index: 1; like this;

```
#progressbar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 400;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change this classes

```
#progressbar li:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    background: lightgray;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 25px;
}

#progressbar #step1:before {
    content: "✓";
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}

#progressbar #step2:before {
    content: "✓";
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}

#progressbar #step3:before {
    content: "✓";
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}

#progressbar #step4:before {
    content: "✓";
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}

#progressbar #step5:before {
    content: "✓";
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

[image]